# Retornar lista a partir de um filho no firebase

Tags: android, firebase, nosql

Bom dia !
Pessoal, estou com uma situação na qual eu quero retornar numa lista todos os dados cujo um dos filhos sejam iguais ao id, na imagem abaixo eu tenho as estruturas dos nós do meu banco no firebase e quero retornar por exemplo o numero de todas as atividades cujo um dos nós (idUsuario) seja igual ao do usuário logado(no caso eu usei uma forma de criptografia para armazenar o id do usuario e o id eu consigo recuperar normalmente), para melhorar, em um banco relacional seria mais ou menos assim: select * from atividades where idUsuario = "A" por exemplo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, para resolver este problema mudei a estrutura que estava usando para salvar os dados no firebase para que ficasse assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma eu consigo trazer mais facilmente os dados que estão amarrados ao usuario indicado:

```
//Evento de consulta
    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //LIMPANDO A LISTA
            atividadeArrayList.clear();

            //Listando cada uma das atividades criadas pelo usuário
            for (DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ //recupera os filhos do nó principal
                Atividade atividade = dados.getValue(Atividade.class);
                atividadeArrayList.add(atividade);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

Mas obrigado Matheus por sua ajuda !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, o problema é que você soma uma "key" com a string "perfil, se você tiver sempre acesso a essa key que vem antes de perfil, você pode fazer uma comparação na Query:

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild('idUsuario').equalTo('seuID');
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot querySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            MyClass id = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyClass.class); // ou String id = dataSnaptshot.getValue(MyClass.class).toString();
            if (id.MyID.equals('xxxxxxxxperfil')) {
                console.log(querySnapshot.getKey());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Matheus, estou testando seu código aqui, mas estou com uma duvida, no caso você instanciou a sua classe Movie como movie, mas fiquei confuso, você pode me explicar a lógica do codigo a seguir: String id = dataSnapshot.getValue(Movie.class);
            if (movie.getLead().equals('xxxxxxxxperfil')) {
                console.log(querySnapshot.getKey());
            }

Comment: Eu tinha pego de um exemplo que utilizei, e não tinha customizado por completo, peço desculpas. Então a MyClass, são digamos os valores que você implementou no firebase entende? Com o getValue você consegue regata-los

Comment: Esse link seria uma referencia perfeita para você dar uma olhada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950532/android-extracting-data-from-firebase-data-snapshot concerteza irá lhe ajudar muito em suas dúvidas

Comment: Bom, eu mudei de ideia e acertei o banco para ficar dessa forma :               +ATIVIDADES
 +idUsuario('xxxxxxxxxxperfil')
  +idAtividade
   +descricao
   +titulo
   +tempo
   +id
   +idUsuario
   ...

Comment: Maravilha  Eduardo